# Django: How to create temporary list in django template with out using template tags?

Tags: python, django

How to create temporary list in django template with out using template tags ?

if not possible to create temp list in django template, then how to use template tags for fixing the below scenario ?

**Simple story:** I have list called **Info** it contains bunch of duplicate values for instance ("hi","hello","hi","hello","hej","hey"). I want to display unique values in one div and all the values in another div  in the same page using the same list **Info**

Please note: I have explained simple scenario here. So may be u think that use **set** method in python for preventing duplicate values. Not possible in my case,I have to  send one object to django template

***In one page there are two div's, it should show different information from the same object.***

**DIV 1:**

```
{% for v in Info %}
       {{v}} // Show unique values ("hi","hello","hej","hey")            
{% endfor %}
```

**DIV 2:**

```
{% for v in Info %}
           {{v}} // Show all the values  ("hi","hello","hi","hello","hej","hey")             
 {% endfor %}
```

Please let me know your views

Comment: can you not send two objects as the template's context ? {'Info': Info, 'unique_info' : set(Info)}

Comment: @srj: Hi, Official answer is NO, because I had given simple example. The fact is,  object contains list. The list length is more than 5000 and more over object contains list inside dict inside dict inside list etc etc

Comment: if that is the case, then a custom filter is probably your best bet. take a look at `regroup` tag if that matches your complex object.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom filter:

```
@register.filter(name='unique')
def unique(value, arg):
    # put your complex unique logic here
    return set(value)
```

refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

use it as `{% for v in Info|unique %} {{v}} {%endfor%}`
note that calling set will mess up the order of your list

Comment: Hi, I failed to express the problem in this space. I am sorry once again. I am going to close this question and come up with new question with exact problem. For your work, I had votedup your answer.

Comment: I posted new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148744/django-using-same-object-how-to-show-2-different-results-in-django-template
Please have a look and let me know your views