# Django: Using same object how to show 2 different results in django template?

Tags: python, django

Using the same object how to SHOW 2 different results using django template ?

In one page there are two div's, it should show different information using the same object.

**INPUT**

**object data has follows**

```
[
    {
        "Google": [
            {
                "Rating": 1,
                "Website": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "Name": "googleplus"
                }
            },
            {
                "Rating": 2,
                "Website": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "Name": "googleplus"
                }
            },
            {
                "Rating": 1,
                "Website": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "Name": "googlemap"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Facebook": [
            {
                "Rating": 1,
                "Website": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "Name": "facebookplus"
                }
            },
            {
                "Rating": 2,
                "Website": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "Name": "facebookplus"
                }
            },
            {
                "Rating": 1,
                "Website": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "Name": "facebookmap"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

DIV 1 (website names should be unique values)

DIV 2 (should display all website names)

*main div start*

loop 1

```
Google  ------  DIV 1 (googleplus, googlemap) ------ DIV 2 (googleplus, googleplus, googlemap)
```

loop 2

```
Facebook  ------  DIV 1 (facebookplus, facebookmap) ------ DIV 2 (facebookplus, facebookplus, facebookmap)
```

*main div end*

Answer (score 1):

Template is used only to display given data. If you want to manipulate data, you have to do this in view. It'll be a lot easier, as you can use normal python syntax.

You can use something like:

```
all_data = <object_name>.objects.all()
unique_data = list(set(all_data))
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to do this on frontend, I would recommend using [Lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq).

But you can of course do it in plain JavaScript:

```
var all_data = ...;
var unique_data = [];
for (i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++) {
    if (unique_data.indexOf(all_data[i]) < 0) unique_data.push(all_data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Those info is not coming from the models instead its a dynamic data from the REST API. and one more thing, i had given simple scenario, list count should be more than 5000

Comment: Then you will have to do this in JavaScript. There is no way to manipulate data that are not present in time of rendering with Python.

Comment: Second option is to create two API endpoints, one with all data and other with unique names.

Comment: the application should be slow when the list length is more than 10,000 and if i create 2 API endpoints..The concept is i have only one object in hands, using that I have show 2 different results

Comment: how to do in javascript ? could you please provide a sample

Comment: You have no other option :)

Comment: Depends on which libraries are you using. I would recommend lodash: https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

Comment: is it possible using plain JavaScript rather than other libraries, which I am not aware :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77430/discussion-between-user2224250-and-domen-blenkus).

Comment: I wouldn't trust to process this size of a list on the front side but I don't believe you have not other option either( in software). What kind of REST API are you using. Is it REST Framework?

Comment: Hi, everyone..I find the solution using template tags with out javascript..thanks everyone for letting your views

Comment: Please write your answer and explain how you've solved it or accept one of existing ones.